# Retrieving more than one value from the function

Tags: sql, postgresql

TableA

```
Id   imge
--   ----
1    1.jpeg
2    2.jpeg
1    1.jpeg
1    1.jpeg
```

o/p needed

```
id     image
------------
1      1.jpeg
       1.jpeg
       1.jpeg
```

I created a function,

```
create or replace function(vid in integer,vimg out varchar) returns setof record as
$$
declare
im varchar;
 begin
 select image into im from tablea wher id=$1;
 return query
 select im;
 $$
 end;
 plpgsql
```

But it's not working. I need to retrieve the images without using the arrays and loops.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your function as `setof record` meaning that it will return any number of rows spanning. You need to redeclare the function and change internal select's to match returning type.

Or I'm wrong and I just miss what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for **[GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(imge) as images
FROM TableA GROUP BY Id;
```

Oh I missed. You were in PostgreSQL, huh?
No worries. There is an equivalent for group_concat in PostgreSQL: **[array_agg](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/04/17/array-agg/)**

```
SELECT id, array_agg(imge)
FROM TableA GROUP BY Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simple function like this is better to write in language `sql` instead of `plpgsql`:

```
create or replace function func(vid in integer)
returns table(vimg varchar)
as
$$
    select imge from tablea where id=$1;
$$ language sql;
```

Anyway, to return multiple records from function your can return either [`table or setof record`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9edc0/1)</kbd>**